# highlight the '#' until line end in richtextbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I have the following text in my RIchTextBox:

```
foo:baa#done baa
a:b#pending  ee
```

and I want highlight all after `#` and before `" "`(espace)

How I do this? I tried make the `end` as IndexOf of `\t` or `" "` but it returns -1.

My code(not working as expected):

```
        string[] lines = list.Lines;
        string line;

        for (int i = 0, max = lines.Length; i < max; i++)
        {
            line = lines[i];
            int start = list.Find("#");
            int end = ??? // I tried list.Find("\t") and list.Find(" ")
            if (-1 != start || -1 != end)
                {
                    list.Select(start, end);
                    list.SelectionColor = color;
                }
          }
```

`list` is an `RichTextBox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
        string[] lines = list.Lines;
        string line;
        int len = 0;
        for (int i = 0, max = lines.Length; i < max; i++)
        {
            line = lines[i];
            int j = i == 0 ? 0 : len;
            string str = Regex.Match(line, @"#.*$").Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                int start = list.Find(str, j, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                if (start != -1)
                {
                    list.Select(start, str.Length);
                    list.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                }
                len += line.Length;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have one problem: the code not selected the last line. how Fix it?

Comment: @TheMask How does your last line look like? Post your text please.

Comment: a:1344 #x <- Red Color
b:1111 #y <- Red Color 
c:222222 #z <- Red Color 
d:5555 #l <- Black Color(The problem, the last line is not changed)

Comment: @TheMask I tried, and it worked. I wonder why it didn't change in your machine. Are our codes the same?

Comment: How to replace a string of an specific line in RichTextBox?

Comment: :yes, I'm using the above code written by you. I tried with 25 lines +

Comment: @TheMask `            string[] lines = list.Lines;
            lines[0] = "ojlovecd";
            list.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
`

Answer (score 3):

Use GetLineFromCharIndex() to get the line number of the Find() method return value.  Then GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1) to know where the next line starts.  That gives you the SelectionStart and SelectionLength values you need to highlight the text.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `line.IndexOf` instead of `list.Find`?

In short, you seem to be searching for characters in your List control, not in the string line.